# Div positioning

Tags: css, html, positioning

I have a three column layout with a container "three-col"

In the right column I have a "Feature Tile" which is basically a 220px wide placeholder with editable content.

I need the "Feature Tile" To move with the "three-col" container, so if the content expands in height, I need the feature tile to move down with it...

May need Jquery - not sure.

Thanks!

**EDIT:** I want the feature tile to always be positioned at the bottom. Move = The div will expand in height based on how much content is inserted - no fixed height

Comment: Where exactly do you want the "Feature Tile" to be, at the top always? Bottom? What does "move with" mean? This could use a good deal of clarification.

Comment: Ah right sorry, I want the feature tile to always be positioned at the bottom. Move = The div will expand in height based on how much content is inserted - no fixed height.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
.right-column {
    position:relative;
}
.featured-tile {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
}
```

This will keep `.featured-tile` at the bottom of `.right-column` no matter what height it is due to variable content.

**UPDATE**: I think I know what you mean, try this instead.

```
.three-col {
    position:relative;
}
.featured-tile {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
}
```

This will keep `.featured-tile` at the bottom of `.three-col`

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wesley_murch/4FKhm/4/

Comment: I tried that and no luck, I can't use position: absolute - remember the height will always change depending on which page you are on based on the content. It's as if the feature tile needs to recognize the height of the "three-col" and position at the bottom

Comment: Some more specifics - The left and middle columns all have content in them so I need the "feature tile" to position to the lowest point of either of the divs

Comment: @Jordy, updated answer and gave a demo. You can try putting some content into left-col to see how it will behave. If this isn't what you need, you'll probably need to provide your actual code, a link to a page, or make a demo on jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered a 2-column layout with the second column being a div with another two columns in it?

Comment: Thanks for your post although, this will only change the layout - not specifically what I'm trying to achieve.